# Cargar vista segun variable - Laravel - Multi Inquilino

Tags: laravel

Estimados tengo un proyecto en Laravel, el cual tiene 2 vistas y de cuerdo a una variable o condición renderea una o u otra vista, pueden ayúdame a decir como puedo o de que depende para carga cada una según el caso , hasta donde he revisado tengo esto,

Averiguando el proyecto es un Multi Inquilino, esta echo con hyn/multi-tenant, TENANCY

```js
if ($hostname) {
carga vista 2, controldores ,etc
}else {
Route::domain(env('APP_URL_BASE'))->group(function() {
otra vista 1, controladors etc

}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que hay un archivo .env donde edito el nombre dela base datos conexión y el host, pero no le doy de que depende la variable $hostname, y la APP_URL_BASE. en la segunda opción en el archivo .env tengo definido la url del sito pero carga la vista 1 en que caso y de que depende cagarria la vista 2 con el paramento $hostname.

puedo dejar mas código si se necesita.

Gracias.

esto es mas o menos lo que se tiene dentro de la carpeta public y dentro de views hay 2 folder mas system y tenant los 2 tienen lo mismo pero el aspecto visual cambia lo de la carpeta system es la que me carga por default pero la otra no puedo hacerla mostrar, no se si es mas claro o se necesita mas información

```js
// archivo routes/web.php

$hostname = app(Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\CurrentHostname::class);

if ($hostname) {
    Route::domain($hostname->fqdn)->group(function() {

        Auth::routes()
        
        //Users
            Route::get('users', 'Tenant\UserController@index')->name('tenant.users.index');
            Route::get('users/create', 'Tenant\UserController@create')->name('tenant.users.create');
            Route::get('users/tables', 'Tenant\UserController@tables');
            Route::get('users/record/{user}', 'Tenant\UserController@record');
            Route::post('users', 'Tenant\UserController@store');
            Route::get('users/records', 'Tenant\UserController@records');
            Route::delete('users/{user}', 'Tenant\UserController@destroy');
            
            } else {
    Route::domain(env('APP_URL_BASE'))->group(function() {

        Route::get('login', 'System\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        Route::post('login', 'System\LoginController@login');
        Route::post('logout', 'System\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        Route::get('phone', 'System\UserController@getPhone');

        Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function() {
            Route::get('logs', '\Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LogViewerController@index');
            Route::get('/', function () {
                return redirect()->route('system.dashboard');
            });
            Route::get('dashboard', 'System\HomeController@index')->name('system.dashboard');

            //Users
            Route::get('users/create', 'System\UserController@create')->name('system.users.create');
            Route::get('users/record', 'System\UserController@record');
            Route::post('users', 'System\UserController@store');
```

Comment: Eso debería poder hacerse desde el controlador, allí haces los condicionales y dependiendo de la condición que se cumpla... colocas la ruta de la vista. Con mayor información podríamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: ok pondre la vista donde esta la condicionesel routes/web.php.

Comment: ya dejo algo mas de código, es una especie de plantilla  hijo de una padre.

Comment: lo que me carga por defecto es to lo que esta en System, la otra carpeta no la logro cargar, voy a dejar una imagen de la estructura.

Comment: Tienes dos login distintos?

Comment: si son 2 login distintos y 2 bd distintas, pero la info es igual, solo cambia lo visual, pero en realidad redirige una y la otra lo que no puedo hacer es redirigir al otro login con la otra vista.

Comment: En realidad son lo mismo solo que la otra vista del otro login o folder lo han personalizado los estilos, la vista por default cargan los estilos de boostrap, en la otra también pero le han metido un .css custom y cambian los colores , imagines, etc. necesito redirigir al otra vista con el otro login etc..